# How to force Spring Security to make https redirect requests when behind a load balancer

Tags: grails, iframe, spring-security, load-balancing, http-redirect

We are currently using AWS ELB -> Apache in front of our Tomcat instance running Grails. We use Apache to redirect http requests to https requests. This works fine for us on our regular site. The issue arrives when trying to embed our site within an iframe on Chrome. Chrome does not like an https site redirecting to an http page (even if that page subsequently redirects to https). The reason this happens is that to Spring Security it looks like we're on http because we're behind a load balancer. Here is the network ping pong from Developer Tools:

[image]

Here is the problem when putting that same page within an iframe on Chrome.

[image]

We have found many solutions that will allow the Spring Security Grails plugin to redirect http requests to https request for certain URL patterns.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23664835/force-grails-weblogic-to-only-redirect-using-https-protocol) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20572667/grails-spring-security-redirect-to-login-page-using-https) are two of these examples. We have already solved this issue by having Apache intercepting http requests and redirecting to https.

The issue is that Chrome won't even make the http request within the iframe. We need an ability to tell Spring Security that even though the [saved request](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/savedrequest/SavedRequest.html) you receive is using http, we need you to change that to https once you complete the authentication.

One solution we thought may work was changing to a relative URL using contextRelative instead of the absolute URL, which Spring Security views as http because of the ELB proxy. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26526830/how-to-make-spring-security-application-to-run-behind-a-proxy) seemed to suggest the same, but the solution also did not change the URL generated when changing contextRelative to "true".

How can we tell the Grails Spring Security plugin to always either format the URLs as relative or force them to an https scheme so that we can run the application within an iframe in Chrome?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to modify the `SavedRequest` then you can implement your own `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` that will override the protocol when it pulls the saved request out of the cache and force it to be https.

Comment: There are basically 2 options we saw when looking to override existing code, change when the URL is saved or change on the redirect. We have overridden HttpSessionRequestCache in order to force the scheme to be saved as https under our specific scenarios.